# Can I delete 500GB worth of iNodes on my HFS+ 4tb Harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, hfs+

I'm trying to free up some space on a 4TB hard drive and using TreeSize to scan all the directories, it came up with a HFS+ Private Data folder which has around 500gb of iNodes.

I'm fairly confident that I can't just delete them as it is a system folder. Do I have to live with that 500gb being allocated to the inodes or is there something I can do  to minimize the amount of storage they use?

I am using this drive for backup purposes, and usually, connect it on a Mac or Windows through MacDrive.

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Please add details about the folder, especially showing data about the inodes.

Comment: I've added to stills. I'm not sure if this is helpful. I have a backup of these folders on another drive which is HSFJ and I don't have any inodes taking space there.

Comment: These inode files could be files recovered after a crash (where the OS/recovery software didn't know the name of the file anymore). What kind of files are these inode files, what happens if you connect the drive to a Mac and analyse from there?

Comment: I've connected the drive to my mac, and after revealing hidden items in Finder, I can't seem to find the folder at all. I'm not proficient in terminal commands so I'm not sure how to get to the files on Mac. I've attached 2 more photos of terminal commands I found online, not sure if they help!